# How to append unspecified amount of lists to list

Tags: python, list, append

My task is to create a list of lists which contain relative and absolute paths of all sql files in my search_dir folder.

The problem is that I can't know beforehand how many files (lists) should my main list contains.

Is there any way to append lists on the run?

```
cnt_of_sql_files = 0

for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(search_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.sql'):
            cnt_of_sql_files +=1

scripts = [[]] * cnt_of_sql_files 

for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(search_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.sql'):
            for index in range(cnt_of_sql_files):
                scripts[index] = [path.join(dirpath, file),
                              path.join(path.basename(dirpath), file)]
print(scripts)
```

Comment: ... yes you use the `.append` method.

Comment: So, just use `scripts = []`, then inside your loop just do `scripts.append([path.join(dirpath, file), path.join(path.basename(dirpath), file)]`.

Comment: What would be your final sample output ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know. Just use the `append` method to add all that is necessary:

```
scripts = [] 

for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(search_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.sql'):
            scripts.append([path.join(dirpath, file),
                           path.join(path.basename(dirpath), file)])
print(scripts)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using python lists, you can add as many elements as you want to a list by using append and extend list methods

`list1.append(list2)` -- adds list2 at the end of list1 as a list

`list1.extend(list2)` -- adds items in list2 at the end of list1 as individual items

Since you need a list of lists, we'd use append.

Also, in order to find relative path of file,
finding relative path of search dirpath relative to search_dir by `path.relpath(dirpath, search_dir)`  and then joining paths with file using `path.join(path.relpath(dirpath, search_dir), file)` is more correct.

Following code should solve your problem :

```
search_dir = "C:\Users\Tanuja\PycharmProjects\practice\practice problems"
    scripts = []
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(search_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.sql'):
                scripts.append([path.join(dirpath, file), path.join(path.relpath(dirpath, search_dir), file)])
    print(scripts)
```

To make your code more pythonic, you can use list comprehension :

```
    scripts = []
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(search_dir):
        scripts.extend([[path.join(dirpath, file), path.join(path.relpath(dirpath, search_dir), file)] for file in files if file.endswith('.sql')])
    print scripts
```